# Convertir un arreglo de bytes en una imagen con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, imagen, google-chart-api

tengo la siguiente situación. Estoy utilizando una api de Google para generar organigramas dinamicos (Google Org Chart), mi proyecto está hecho en asp.net mvc, pero en esta ocasión solo utilizo JS.

El problema que se me presenta es que necesito mostrar una imagen que tengo alojada en mi base de datos con el gestor SQL Server, el tipo de dato es de varbinary...

Cuando lo intento mostrar por el momento solo puedo mostrar el arreglo de bytes pero quisiera saber si alguien me pudiera apoyar para realizar esa conversion.

El problema está específicamente en la parte de var Imagen.

```html
<!-- Scripts JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "/Conocenos/Organigrama_Json",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dt) {

                var dataArray = [];

                $.each(dt, function (i, item) {
                    dataArray.push([item.IDSERVPUB, item.NOMBREPERSONAL, item.NOMBRAMIENTO, item.NIVEL, item.FOTOPERSONAL]);
                });

                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                data.addColumn('string', 'Entity');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ReportEntity');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');


                for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
                    //no cambiar nombre de variables
                    var Employee_ID = dataArray[i][0].toString();
                    var Employee_Name = dataArray[i][1];
                    var Title = dataArray[i][2];
                    var ReportTo = dataArray[i][3] != null ? dataArray[i][3].toString() : '';
                    //necesito convertir este arreglo de bytes en una imagen
                    var Image = dataArray[i][4]; // solo muestro el arreglo 


                    //si el valor el null que no lo muestre en el diagrama
                    if (Employee_Name == null) {
                        Employee_Name = "";
                    }
                    data.addRows([[{
                        v: Employee_ID,
                        f: Employee_Name + '<br/><b>' + Title + '</b>' + '<br/><b>' + Image
                                           
                    }, ReportTo, Title]]);
                }


                var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart($("#chartOrg")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });

            },
            failure: function (dt) {
                alert(dt);
            },
            error: function (dt) {
                alert(dt);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero tienes que saber qué tipo de imagen es (`jpeg`, `gif` o `png`), luego tienes que codificar los bytes en Base64 y por último tienes que ponerlo en el atributo `src` de un `<img>` de la siguiente manera:

```
<img src="data:image/__FORMATO__;base64,__BYTES_EN_BASE64__">
```

En tu código tienes la imagen, en `var Image = dataArray[i][4];`. Tendrías que codificarla en Base64 con `var Image_Base64 = btoa(Image)`, pero no es compatible con todos los navegadores, por lo que te recomiendo guardar las imágenes ya codificadas en la base de datos.

Pero... te falta el tipo de imagen. Puedes guardarlo en la base de datos o bien convertir todas las imagenes al formato que prefieras antes de guardarlas en la base de datos.

Por tu código, parece como que `Imagen` no es una cadena binaria, sino un array de bytes. Si es así, necesitarías convertirla primero, si decides usar javascript y `btoa()`:

```
function bin2string(array){
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i){
        result+= (String.fromCharCode(array[i]));
    }
    return result;
}
var Imagen_Bin_String = bin2string(Imagen);
var Imagen_Base64 = btoa(Imagen_Bin_String);
```

Nota: la función `bin2string()` la he sacado de https://gist.github.com/taterbase/2784890 .

---

```
data.addRows( [ [
    {
        v: Employee_ID,
        f: Employee_Name +
           '<br/><b>' +
           Title + '</b>' +
           '<br/><b>' +
           '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + Imagen_Base64 + '">'
    },
    ReportTo,
    Title
] ] );
```

Comment: Estoy implementando lo que me apoyaste, la etiquieta <img> quedó así 

<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,Image_Base64">

pero en la consola me marca el siguiente error:

GET data:image/jpg;base64,Image_Base64 net::ERR_INVALID_URL

¿Estaré equivocado en algo?.

Comment: He puesto al final el código para añadir la imagen.

Comment: Excelente, funcionó